# How to implement a ViewPager based activity with multiple drill down fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I have a need to implement an android activity, that has an action bar full of 4 action tabs.

In each action tab, there are a number of fragments that need to be displayed, and changed out, depending on user interaction (user selects an item from the list).

I need to find a clean way to swap out the views (and put them on the back-stack), so that the back buttons work correctly, and that state (items selected, etc) is properly propagated to the next fragment.

Can somebody point me in the right direction ?

Comment: you'd need to implement your own back button logic, for viewpager to work, as viewpager doesnt keep track of which page came when

Comment: the keeping track is rather a simple logic